# Material-ui Table Server side Pagination in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I need material-ui pagination sorting and filtering using server side. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't build a solution from scratch for you - please consider providing some code you have written that we can look at.

---

Below is a **example** of what your request can look like, your backend will then need to

A simple way to achieve this is to shape your request like this:

```json
// This is a sample structure - don't just copy and paste. Adjust it to your needs
{
    "page" : 1,
    "pageSize" : 25,
    "filters" : [
        {
            "field" : "anyFieldName",
            "direction" : "ASC"
        }
    ],
    "sortBy" : "date"
}
```

And your server which will talk to your data store will parse and use the above qualifiers to sort, filter, and limit the size.

Comment: mui-datatables Solved the issue thank you